# Can "sparse zero" be set to the value other than (BYTE)0x00, really?

Tags: windows, file, ntfs, sparse-file

If I understood the text correctly, [Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365564) contains an innuendo what it can:

> The default data value of a sparse file is zero; however, it can be
>   set to other values.

However, combing thru related text gave me absolutely no signs of corresponding `FSCTL`s which allows sets or retrieves sparse zero value. So, is there a mistake in the introduction or there are undocumented FS control codes?

Comment: A file system driver could alter this.  There are no FSCTL codes.

Answer (score 2):

Probably really poor writing.  Yes,the default value is zero and you can't make the default value be anything except zero.

You can, however, change those zeros to whatever you want by WriteFile. Which, of course, is not what you are asking for.